# Is there an environment variable to force multithreading for IntelMPI on Linux?

Tags: multithreading, environment-variables, intel-mpi

MPICH and OpenMPI both are implementations of MPI and have each an environment variable, respectively MPIR_CVAR_DEFAULT_THREAD_LEVEL and OMPI_MPI_THREAD_LEVEL, to force the level of thread support, even when the initialisation is done through MPI_Init and not MPI_Init_thread.

Though this is going against the MPI norm, this is extremely useful in a lot of practical cases.

I've gone through the IntelMPI documentation ([here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference.html)) to try and find the equivalent variable in IntelMPI but came back empty handed.

Does such a variable exist in IntelMPI? Have I missed it?

Thank you for any help.